# Redirect directory to Azure url

Tags: redirect, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have written this rule in webconfig to redirect all my resources in thsi folder to my azure blob but it is not showing any image there.

```
 <rule name="RewriteIncomingCdnRequest" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^/CDN/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://stplatformstorage.blob.core.windows.net/static/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
```

http://sttest.azurewebsites.net/CDN/image_cdn-trans.png
this should redirect to azure storage....

image url on storage
https://stplatformstorage.blob.core.windows.net/static/image_cdn-trans.png

Comment: Seems to be working on my end. 
http://sttest.azurewebsites.net/CDN/image_cdn-trans.png redirects me to http://stplatformstorage.blob.core.windows.net/static/image_cdn-trans.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a bad regular expression - as written, url="^/CDN/(.*)$" would only match /CDN/image_cdn-trans.png - because "^" means "from start of..." --  what you really need is url="`^.*/CDN/(.*)$`"  and then use the matching group {R:1} - for:

```
<rule name="RewriteIncomingCdnRequest" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^.*/CDN/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false"/>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://stplatformstorage.blob.core.windows.net/static/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The URL Rewrite module has a great test function to test your regular expressions.